# Idiomatic way to store a closure for reuse?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

Passing closures in Rust is quite straightforward, however when storing closures for re-use, there are multiple solutions (use generic function types, reference closures or box, box with `'static` lifetime or not?...).

While I've muddled through this multiple times using different kinds of boxed types, read over similar Q&A's and could even hazard a guess at answering this question. I don't have a feel for how to handle this, even for the simple/obvious case, or what a good starting point would be.

To make the question more concrete, what would be a good way to make this example store functions for re-use, using the builder pattern to store closures to be called later.

```
// This example looks a bit long but its really very simple.

// * This example is most of the way to implementing the builder pattern,
//   it ust runs the code immediately instead of storing input
//   to run on `build()`.
// * Changes should only be needed where the comment `stored closures:`
//   has been written.
// * I've attempted to make this example as generic as possible,
//   but not _so_ simple that the answer wont apply to real-world use (hopefully!).

struct MyActions {
    num: i32,
    times: i32,

    // stored closures: should be stored here.
    // update_fn: Option<Fn(...)>,
    // twiddle_fn: Option<Fn(...)>,
}

impl MyActions {
    pub fn new(num: i32) -> Self {
        return MyActions {
            num: num,
            times: 1,
        }
    }

    pub fn build(self) -> i32 {
        // stored closures:
        // should run both actions if they're defined and return the result.
        return self.num;
    }

    pub fn num_times(mut self, times: i32) -> Self {
        self.times = times;
        self
    }

    pub fn num_update<F>(mut self, func: F) -> Self
        where
        F: Fn(i32) -> i32
    {
        // stored closures: run immediately for now
        for _ in 0..self.times {
            self.num = func(self.num);
        }
        self
    }

    pub fn num_twiddle<F>(mut self, func: F) -> Self
        where
        F: Fn(i32) -> i32
    {
        // stored closures: run immediately for now
        for _ in 0..self.times {
            self.num = func(self.num);
        }
        self
    }
}

// no changes needed here
fn main() {
    let act = MyActions::new(133);
    let num_other: i32 = 4;

    // builder pattern (currently executes immediately).
    let result = act
        .num_times(8)
        .num_update(|x| x * 2 + num_other)
        .num_twiddle(|x| (((x / 2) - 1) ^ (x + 1)) ^ num_other)
        .build();

    // Lets say we would want this example to work,
    // where 'times' is set after defining both functions.
    /*
    let result = act
        .num_update(|x| x * 2 + num_other)
        .num_twiddle(|x| (((x / 2) - 1) ^ (x + 1)) ^ num_other)
        .num_times(8)  // <-- order changed here
        .build();
     */

    println!("done: {}", result);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The idiomatic solution to this is to box the closures. While boxing a closure and calling it later incurs allocation overhead and dynamic dispatch overhead, in most cases it is negligible and the `MyAction` type stays easily usable with friendly error messages.

Alternatively the different functions can be generic fields of the `MyAction` struct, which store the closure without indirection. This can yield enormous speedups in some cases, but the usability of such a type decreases due to more complex error messages and the inability to move `MyAction` objects around freely.

If the boxed version clearly shows up in profiling as slow, then you can move to the generic version. Otherwise I suggest to stay with the easy to use boxed version.

> box with 'static lifetime or not?

Again, for simplicity you can use the `'static` lifetime, but then your `MyAction` struct can only store closures that do not borrow their environment. If you use a lifetime on the `MyAction` struct and forward it to the closures, you'll be able to borrow your environment, at the cost of generic arguments, which again might end up making the `MyAction` struct harder to use correctly.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, since some of the syntax for closure ownership isn't obvious, here is my attempt at an idiomatic/rustic version of the code in the question.

*(if theres any issues with it, please comment or update it directly).*

- Used Boxed closure, in general this seems to be the preferred method since it means multiple different closure types can be stored in the same struct.
- Not using `'static`, this allows the caller to use variables in their environment (see `num_other` use in the question). Instead use a lifetime on the `struct`.

Working example using boxed closures inheriting the container structs lifetime:

```
use std::boxed::Box;

struct MyActions<'a> {
    num: i32,
    times: i32,

    update_fn:  Option<Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32 + 'a>>,
    twiddle_fn: Option<Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32 + 'a>>,
}

impl <'a> MyActions<'a> {
    pub fn new(num: i32) -> Self {
        return MyActions {
            num: num,
            times: 1,
            update_fn: None,
            twiddle_fn: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn build(self) -> i32 {
        let mut num = self.num;

        if let Some(update_fn) = self.update_fn {
            for _ in 0..self.times {
                num = update_fn(num);
            }
        }

        if let Some(twiddle_fn) = self.twiddle_fn {
            for _ in 0..self.times {
                num = twiddle_fn(num);
            }
        }

        return num;
    }

    pub fn num_times(mut self, times: i32) -> Self {
        self.times = times;
        self
    }

    pub fn num_update<F>(mut self, func: F) -> Self
        where
        F: 'a,
        F: Fn(i32) -> i32,
    {
        self.update_fn = Some(Box::new(func));
        self
    }

    pub fn num_twiddle<F>(mut self, func: F) -> Self
        where
        F: 'a,
        F: Fn(i32) -> i32,
    {
        self.twiddle_fn = Some(Box::new(func));
        self
    }
}

// no changes needed here
fn main() {
    let act = MyActions::new(133);
    let num_other: i32 = 4;

    // builder pattern (currently executes immediately).
    let result = act
        .num_times(8)
        .num_update(|x| x * 2 + num_other)
        .num_twiddle(|x| (((x / 2) - 1) ^ (x + 1)) ^ num_other)
        .build();

    println!("done: {}", result);

    // Lets say we would want this example to work,
    // where 'times' is set after defining both functions.
    let act = MyActions::new(133);
    let result = act
        .num_update(|x| x * 2 + num_other)
        .num_twiddle(|x| (((x / 2) - 1) ^ (x + 1)) ^ num_other)
        .num_times(8)  // <-- order changed here
        .build();

    println!("done: {}", result);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile anymore since 2021 because of [E0782](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0782.html#error-code-e0782).

Comment: @Marv it compiled for me w/ rust-1.64.0 but warned about the need for `dyn`, now resolved.